# How to use restart app in debug mode in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Hi i am making a simple project(android and IOS) about multiple languages using getx and shared_preferences.
I want to restart application every time language change(to load all configs in selected language). I use [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) flugin and everything look fine.

But the problem is I run app in debug mode and every time app restart, it close debug mode. So how to make app restart in both debug mode and release mode?

Please help me. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android studio, you can use the "Attach Debugger" icon which is a few icons to the right of the "Debug" icon.

But for what specifically do you even need to restart your app? I can't think of any use case that needs an explicit restart to work.

Comment: My manager wants it, after a short discuss about this feature, he agrees not to restart it. thank you for your help. it helps me to understand concept of Flutter more.

Comment: No Problem, feel free to ask if you need anything else!